# Are exceptions supported by processor?

Tags: c++

I thinking about exceptions in c++

**Are they supported by procesor?
A or B idea is faster?**

Idea A = handle errors by throwing

Idea B = handle errors by returning certain value

A:

```
int divide(int a, int b);


void sth(){
  try
  {
    int ret = divide(10,0);
  }
  catch (const std::invalid_argument& e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
int divide(int a, int b){
  if(b == 0)
    throw std::invalid_argument( "B = 0 ?!" );

    return a/b;
}
```

B)

```
int divide(int a, int b);


void sth(){
  int ret = divide(10,0); // we want to catch error as above, don't worry about result
  if(ret == -1)
    std::cout << "Divide by 0!" << std::endl;
  else if(ret == -2)
    std::cout << "Other error" << std::endl;
}
int divide(int a, int b){
  if(b == 0)
    return -1;

    return a/b;
}
```

Comment: This is a hot topic, people have strong views for both sides of the argument. Beware of biased answers.

Comment: B is obviously not practical - why  would -1/1 return an error? And neither addresses your headline question.

Comment: @latedeveloper you have right, but I want to present only idea.. Where return is opposite to throw, please focus on idea not on this certain example, assume we only use `divide(x,0)` - to catch error not `divide(-1,1)` - I should return struct but this is not the problem of this topic

Comment: I understand that this is not what you are focusing on, but your B variant doesn't work reliably. What if I tried to call `divide(3, -3)`? Or, due to rounding, even `divide(3, -2)`? You'd get a divide by zero error! Don't use a possible output value to signal that the input is invalid, it doesn't work. You have to communicate this using something other than the return value. And since C++ only supports returning one value, you'd better create a struct, with two members: `error_code` and `result`. Or, return one of them and pass the other by reference, so that you can update it.

Comment: Relevant read I have encoutered recently: http://nibblestew.blogspot.com/2017/01/measuring-execution-performance-of-c.html Bottom line, performance varies on case-by-case. IMHO the test setup is too simple, and yet already show dependency on use-case. I agree with the conclusion presented there: 
*The proper question to ask is "under which circumstances are exceptions faster". As we have seen here, the answer is surprisingly complex.*

Answer (score 4):

The usual thinking on which to choose is: it depends on how often you expect it to fail.

- If you expect it to fail often, post-checks are better since the check will likely be cheaper than handling an exception.
- If you expect failure to be rarer, exceptions may be a better choice since then you're not wasting resources constantly checking what you know is probably correct. Use **exceptions** to handle **exceptional** circumstances.

Of course, this is entirely subjective though without benchmarking a particular scenario. At what point is failure rare enough to warrant exceptions?

This doesn't answer your title question, but it's a good guideline to keep in mind. Hopefully someone else can answer the other part.